# Transporting drugs through highsec

Tags: eve-online

What's the best way to transport drugs through highsec? Preferably with minimal sec status loss, and zero drug loss. I've heard you could just speed through in a fast frigate, how fast do you really have to be? Are there other ways?

Comment: Unless things have changed since I last played 6 months or so ago, there's so little trade in illegal drugs in high-sec that's pretty much a moot question. There's really no point in moving them through high-sec.

Comment: @RossRidge I'd like to transport them into highsec, so I can use them in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot avoid customs and get a standings hit/fine, but you *can* avoid being shot at if you want to avoid having the drugs confiscated.

Basically, you'd jump in and the dialog to surrender your goods will appear. Keep that window up and quickly (use a blockade runner with a cloak or a fast interceptor) and warp to the next gate. Right before you jump, click "No" to the dialog to not surrender the goods and jump through. Rinse and repeat.

It's considered exploiting to dodge customs completely much like dodging CONCORD. Their cargo scans can scan blockade runners and warp core stabs won't help, either.

As an aside, I recommend using an alt as the standing hits will eventually make you shoot on sight in the chosen factions that you're moving the goods through. Also, the fines *can* make your wallet negative!

Comment: You lose standing per stack, not per item.

Answer (score 2):

The @Nathan's answer is correct for the time of answering, but since release 118.6 (that was rollled out at the end of June 2016) there are no restrictions for transporting drugs in high sec. 
[Source](https://forums-archive.eveonline.com/message/6521354/)